# Interval for uniform convergence

Tags: proof-verification, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

For $n$ a positive integer, let $f_n(x)$ be the continuous function $\frac{1}{1+nx}$ with domain the positive real numbers.
Let $f (x)$ be the pointwise limit of the sequence $\{ f_n(x)\}_{n\geq1}$ of functions. On which of the following
intervals is the convergence $f_n\to f$  uniform? Choose all the correct options:

(a) $(0,1)$

(b) $(1,2)$

(c) $(2,1)$

(d) None of the above.

My attempt:

We have $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+nx}.$ Therefore the pointwise limit is $f(x) = 1$.

Now using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, we have to find a $N$ which only depends on $\epsilon$ but not $x.$

$|\frac{1}{1+nx}-1| <\epsilon$ $\implies \frac{nx}{1+nx}<\epsilon \implies n > \frac{-\epsilon}{x(1-\epsilon)}.$

I am stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, for each $x>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+nx}=0$. The convergence is uniform on $(1,2)$, because if $x\in(1,2)$, then$$\left\lvert\frac1{1+nx}-0\right\rvert=\frac1{1+nx}<\frac1{1+n},$$since $x>1$. So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1{1+N}<\varepsilon$ and then$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N)(\bigl(\forall x\in[0,1]\bigr):\left\lvert\frac1{1+nx}-0\right\rvert<\frac1{1+n}\leqslant\frac1{1+N}<\varepsilon.$$

And the convergence is *not* uniform on $(0,1)$, $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f_n\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac12$.

Logically, $(2,1)=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid2<x<1\}=\emptyset$. So, the convergence *is* uniform there.

Comment: $f_n(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{2}$ on $(0,1)$ . So how does that imply not uniform. Will you please explain?

Comment: I am asserting that this sequence of function doesn't converge uniformly to the null function in $(0,1)$, which means that$$(\exists\varepsilon>0)(\forall N\in\mathbb N)(\exists n\in\mathbb N)(\exists x\in(0,1)):n\geqslant N\text{ and }\bigl\lvert f_n(x)\bigr\rvert\geqslant\varepsilon.$$So, I take $\varepsilon=\frac1n$. Let $N\in\mathbb N$. I then take $n=N$ and $x=\frac1n$. Note that $n\geqslant N$ and that $x\in(0,1)$. And we have$$\bigl\lvert f_n(x)\bigr\rvert=\frac12\geqslant\varepsilon.$$